The textbox for chat suspension length has odd functionality, making it difficult to issue a chat suspension
The chat suspension tool has a textbox that allows you to input a number of hours in before hitting the "suspend this user for..." button. At present, though, clicking directly on the hours input field will treat it as though you clicked the "suspend" button. This makes it very difficult to input a correct duration before suspending.
Here's a GIF that showcases the problem:

Each time you click the textbox for the hours length, it'll prompt you as though you're actually trying to suspend a user. A workaround is to dismiss the popup, make the modifications for the hours as you originally intended, then hit the "suspend this user for" button. This is darn near impossible to do on mobile, though!
Could this be fixed?

Yeah, on my phone the keyboard won't even pop up, not even when dismissing the prompt. I also hit 'OK' a few times and it didn't issue even a 1 hour suspension. Find me the Mod Room on MSE chat if someone wants a link to a profile ;)

No sock for testing? @Tink

@Sha Nope, my sock doesn't have chat privileges or a chat profile :)

Yeah my implementation for Add a confirmation dialog before suspending people on chat was not, let's say, on the smartest end of the scale. In my defense, nobody else seems to have noticed this since July either 
Back then, I added code to ask for confirmation, but it didn't actually ask

Do you really mean to suspend this user?

but instead it asked

Did you really mean to click somewhere in the suspension form?

which technically includes the button (and thus worked) but is not the most useful way of doing it because it also includes the text box.
I guess most chat suspensions use the default 1 hour and that's why it took a bit to be noticed.
Fixed now, thanks!

And the "destroy user" button still work? ;-)

@ShadowWizard don't tempt me do try

But... but... you'd lose the Top Pinger! :-D
